# ASP.NET Treeview From Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, tree

I have a data hierarchy path separated by '/', currently in a SQL Server 2008 table. How can I display this path as a TreeView in my ASP.NET C# application.

Here is an example of what the table looks like:

```
Parent1/
Parent2/
Parent2/Child1
Parent1/Child1
Parent1/Child1/GrandChild1
Parent1/Child2
```

I would like to display it something like this:

```
+ Parent1
  - Child1
    - GrandChild1
  - Child2
+ Parent2
  - Child1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing to do with SQL.

- Take an individual path, say `foo/bar/baz/bat`.
- Split that string into an array of path segments: `string[]segments = path.split('/') ;`. This array represents the path of nodes in the tree you're going to construct.
- Iterate over that list of segments to build out the tree structure desired — whether that be a treeview control or some other sort of tree structure — if the node at a given path in the tree doesn't exist, add it as you traverse the tree.
- When you get to the leaf node, add the desired data related to that path.

Repeat the above procedure for each path in your list of paths.